# How to render singly Linked list in MVC View page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, treeview

As I am trying to create a TreeView folder structure in MVC. I have class file something like the below.

**Class File**

```
 public class TreeViewFolder
 {
    public string FolderPath { get; set; }
    public string FolderName { get; set; }
    public List<TreeViewFolder> MyTreeList { get; set; }
 }
```

I need to render that above list in MVC View. I have no idea how to render single linked list data in MVC View. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to display? Just the hierarchy of folder names?

Answer (score 3):

You could create an extension method that uses recursion to build `<ul>` and `<li>` elements to show the hierarchy of folders

```
public static class FolderTreeExtensions
{
  public static MvcHtmlString FolderTree(this HtmlHelper helper, TreeViewFolder folder)
  {
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(TreeLeaf(folder));
  }

  // Recursive function
  private static string TreeLeaf(TreeViewFolder folder)
  {
    StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();
    TagBuilder div = new TagBuilder("div");
    div.InnerHtml = folder.FolderName;
    html.Append(div.ToString());
    if (folder.MyTreeList != null)
    {
      foreach (TreeViewFolder subFolder in folder.MyTreeList)
      {
        html.Append(TreeLeaf(subFolder));
      }
    }
    TagBuilder item = new TagBuilder("li");
    item.InnerHtml = html.ToString();
    TagBuilder container = new TagBuilder("ul");
    container.InnerHtml = item.ToString();       
    return container.ToString();
  }
}
```

Then in your controller, initialize and populate and instance of `TreeViewFolder`, and in the view

```
@model TreeViewFolder
....
@Html.FolderTree(Model)
```

Then style the elements to suit your requirements

Note: either add a `using` statement in the view or add a reference to the `<namespaces>` section of `web.config`

Comment: i don't need to initialize and populate data in controller and pass it to method as it is all taken care of in the Menu.cs Class. How do i pass the returned `MvcHtmlString` on partial view to view it. As your guide, i created another method that takes the string and returning it as `MvcHtmlString`.

Comment: @ARr0w, Your comment seems related to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43087175/mvc-dynamic-menu-populating-plain-text) and should be made there :)