# Show List of items in a Tree like structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a hierarchy of tables [All tables have only 2 fields Id,Name] which are related to each other and the structre islike

```
 Level1 ->

    Level2  [ Foreign key of Level1 Id]
       ->
        Level3  [ Foreign key of Level2 Id]
          ->
          Statement [ Foreign key of Level3 Id]
```

And finally a table mapItems with fields UserId,StatementId [ Foreign key to StatementId] .It stores all statements applicable for a user

While showing the items in UI i have to follow a Tree like structre.

In my controller i have List as model

I can read it one by one like this

```
model.FirstOrDefault().statement.level3.level2.level1
```

How easily i can do this?

Comment: I suggest your model/view model needs to be changed to represent a hierarchical structure (with properties like `int ID`, `string Name` and `List<YourModel> Children`) to you can render a tree. For example, using an extension method like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146524/how-to-render-singly-linked-list-in-mvc-view-page/27147744#27147744)

Comment: But in my case every level has a reference to top of the level as well. SO how can i show those?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean (that's not what you question indicates). You have shown that `Level1` items have a collection of child objects (`Level2`). Each `Level2` object has a collection of child objects (`Level3`) and each `Level3` object has a collection of child objects (`Statement`) - much like a windows folder structure. Although its unclear why you have a second 'mapping' table as opposed to the standard `ID`, `ParentID`, `Name` table structure?

Comment: Sorry 4 confusion . i man the same ID ParentID Name structre only