# How to show IEnumerable hierarchy on cshtml?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a object list as model on my .cshtml page.

```
@model IEnumerable<someObject>
```

Each object have name, id and parentid.

Right now I am showing data as simple list:

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <li>
   ...
   </li>
}
</ul>
```

and it looks like:

```
---------
|test1  | //id=1 parentid=0
|test2  | //id=2 parentid=1
|test3  | //id=3 parentid=2
|test4  | //id=4 parentid=2
|test5  | //id=5 parentid=0
---------
```

BUT I need to show it as:

```
---------------
|test1        | //id=1 parentid=0
|   test2     | //id=2 parentid=1
|      test3  | //id=3 parentid=2
|      test4  | //id=4 parentid=2
|test5        | //id=5 parentid=0
---------------
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Create a hierarchical view model so you can represent what you want to display. You can also use an extension to recursively generate the hierarchy (refer [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146524/how-to-render-singly-linked-list-in-mvc-view-page/27147744#27147744))

Comment: Looks... very complicated.. .especially because I need to show hierarchy only once (in case of several usage, it might be an option)

Answer (score 2):

You need to consider using recursive function. For that you need to change your data structure in such a way that it can be used in a recursive function.
Please see an example I have created

```
public class Menu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Menu> ChildMenus { get; set; }
}
```

You can use the above class in your model
And in your view, you can create your recursive function as the sample below:

```
@model List<TestNs.Models.Menu>
```

```html
<div>
@DisplayMenu(Model)
</div>
```

```html
@helper DisplayMenu(List<Menu> menuItems)
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in menuItems)
        {
            <li>
                @item.Name
                @if (item.ChildMenus != null && item.ChildMenus.Any())
                {
                    @DisplayMenu(item.ChildMenus)
                }
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

And finally from your controller, you can prepare your menu and call send it to your view. Please use the sample shown below:

```
   public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var menu = new List<Menu>
        {
            new Menu
            {
                Id = 1,
                ParentId = 0,
                Name = "Home",
                ChildMenus = new List<Menu>
                {
                    new Menu
                    {
                        Id = 2,
                        ParentId = 1,
                        Name = "Business",
                        ChildMenus = null
                    },
                    new Menu
                    {
                        Id = 3,
                        ParentId = 1,
                        Name = "Social",
                        ChildMenus = new List<Menu>
                        {
                            new Menu
                            {
                                Id = 4,
                                ParentId = 3,
                                Name = "Educ",
                                ChildMenus = null
                            },
                            new Menu
                            {
                                Id = 5,
                                ParentId = 3,
                                Name = "opp",
                                ChildMenus = null
                            }
                        },
                    }
                },
            } 
        };
        return View(menu);
    }
}
```

Put that on and see how you can achieve what you want. Of course you need to pull your data from your data source. 
I hope this help you to address your issue.
Enjoy!!

Answer (score 0):

You always can use `DisplayTemplate` and `EditorTemplate` for this case.

You should create folder `EditorTemplates`(`DisplayTemplates`) in `Views\Shared` and create file `someObject.cshtml`.

in this file you should do something like this:

```
@model MVC.ViewModels.someObject

<li>
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id) <-- here you can putt all properties that you need
@if (Model.SubObjects != null && Model.SubObjects.Any())
{
    <ul>
        @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Translates)
    </ul>
}
</li>
```

But in this case you should have in your `ViewModel` not `ParentId`, but Collection of `SubObjects`, i mean this:

```
public class someObject
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public IEnumerable<someObject> SubObjects {get; set;}
}
```

Then on your View you can use it like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<someObject>

<ul>
   @Html.EditorForModel()
</ul>
```

Note that you don't need any `for` or `foreach` now.