# How to make multilevel menu from categories

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an categories model that can have multiple subcategories. I want to show those categories in my menu, but can only get one level down. How do I make an multilevel menu soloution?
I have tried with an helper method inside the partial view, but it loads it double.

The Category model :

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Fill in a Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category ParentCategory { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection Listings { get; set; }
}
```

CategoriesController that fill the partial view _Menu

```
[ChildActionOnly]
   public ActionResult GetMenu()
   {
       IList<Category> catAll = new List<Category>();
       catAll = categoriesRepository.All.ToList();
       return PartialView("_Menu", catAll);
   }
```

The Partial view _Menu

```
@model List
@foreach (var mp in Model.Where(p => p.ParentCategoryId == null))
{

        @mp.Name

            @foreach (var menuLevel2 in Model.Where(p => p.ParentCategoryId.Equals(mp.CategoryId)))
            {
                @menuLevel2.Name                 
                        @ShowTree(Model, mp.CategoryId);                    
                }
            }


}
    @helper ShowTree(List foos, int ParentId)
{
foreach (var menuLevel2 in foos)
{
    if (menuLevel2.ParentCategoryId == ParentId)
    {
                @menuLevel2.Name
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You should start with a hierarchical view model which represent you menu structure and then you could write an extension method to display the menu - something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146524/how-to-render-singly-linked-list-in-mvc-view-page/27147744#27147744)