# Add a third level to dynamically accordion menu MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, accordion

I used the following code to create a dynamic menu. I found it at http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/dynamic-accordion-menu-or-vertical-menu-using-jquery-in-Asp-Net-mvc-1123.aspx

My model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
namespace Accordion_Menu_MVC.Models
{
public class MenuModel
{
   public List<MainMenu> MainMenuModel { get; set; }
   public List<SubMenu> SubMenuModel { get; set; }
}
public class MainMenu
{
   public int ID;
   public string MainMenuItem;
   public string MainMenuURL;
}
public class SubMenu
{
   public int MainMenuID;
   public string SubMenuItem;
   public string SubMenuURL;
}
}
```

My controller

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Accordion_Menu_MVC.Models;
namespace Accordion_Menu_MVC.Controllers
{
public class HomeController : Controller
{
   //
   // GET: /Home/
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       MenuModel ObjMenuModel = new MenuModel();
       ObjMenuModel.MainMenuModel = new List<MainMenu>();
       ObjMenuModel.MainMenuModel = GetMainMenu();
       ObjMenuModel.SubMenuModel = new List<SubMenu>();
       ObjMenuModel.SubMenuModel = GetSubMenu();
       return View(ObjMenuModel);
   }
   public List<MainMenu> GetMainMenu()
   {
       List<MainMenu> ObjMainMenu = new List<MainMenu>();
       ObjMainMenu.Add(new MainMenu { ID = 1, MainMenuItem = "Mobile", MainMenuURL = "http://www.google.com" });
       ObjMainMenu.Add(new MainMenu { ID = 2, MainMenuItem = "Speaker", MainMenuURL = "#" });
       ObjMainMenu.Add(new MainMenu { ID = 3, MainMenuItem = "Watch", MainMenuURL = "#" });
       ObjMainMenu.Add(new MainMenu { ID = 4, MainMenuItem = "Clothes", MainMenuURL = "#" });
       return ObjMainMenu;
   }
   public List<SubMenu> GetSubMenu()
   {
       List<SubMenu> ObjSubMenu = new List<SubMenu>();
       ObjSubMenu.Add(new SubMenu { MainMenuID = 1, SubMenuItem = "Apple", SubMenuURL = "#" });
       ObjSubMenu.Add(new SubMenu { MainMenuID = 1, SubMenuItem = "Samsung", SubMenuURL = "#" });
       ObjSubMenu.Add(new SubMenu { MainMenuID = 1, SubMenuItem = "Nokia", SubMenuURL = "#" });
       ObjSubMenu.Add(new SubMenu { MainMenuID = 1, SubMenuItem = "Motorola", SubMenuURL = "#" });
       return ObjSubMenu;
      }
      }
     }
```

My view

```
@model Accordion_Menu_MVC.Models.MenuModel  
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Dynamic Accordion Menu Using jQuery in ASP.NET MVC";
}
<link href="Css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"      type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#accordian h3").click(function () {
       $("#accordian ul ul").slideUp();
       if (!$(this).next().is(":visible")) {
           $(this).next().slideDown();
       }
   });
});
 </script>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home"))
   {
 <div id="accordian">
     <ul>
              <li>
              @{
  foreach (var MenuItem in Model.MainMenuModel)
  {
  var SubMenuItem = Model.SubMenuModel.Where(m => m.MainMenuID ==  MenuItem.ID);

      <h3><a href="@MenuItem.MainMenuURL"> @MenuItem.MainMenuItem </a></h3>

        if (SubMenuItem.Count() > 0)
        {
             <ul>
                      @foreach (var SubItem in SubMenuItem)
                      {
                          <li><a h  href='@SubItem.SubMenuURL'>@SubItem.SubMenuItem</a></li>
                      }
             </ul>
         }

      }
   }
     </ul>
  </div>   
   }
```

My css

```
<style>
 /*Basic reset*/
 * {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
 body {
     background: White;
     font-family: Nunito, arial, verdana;
 }
#accordian {
     background: #004050;
     width: 250px;
     margin: 100px auto 0 auto;
     color: white;
     /*Some cool shadow and glow effect*/
     box-shadow:
              0 5px 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6),
              0 0 200px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  }
/*heading styles*/
#accordian h3 {
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 34px;
     padding: 0 10px;
     cursor: pointer;
     /*fallback for browsers not supporting gradients*/
     background: #003040;
     background: linear-gradient(#003040, #002535);
  }
/*heading hover effect*/
 #accordian h3:hover {
     text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
 }
  /*iconfont styles*/
  #accordian h3 a {
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 12px;
     line-height: 27px;    
     padding: 0 15px;
     /*transition for smooth hover animation*/
  }
 #accordian h3 a:hover {
 color:#E1E1E1;   
  }
/*list items*/
 #accordian li {
     list-style-type: none;
  background:#4D6974;
 }
 /*links*/
    #accordian ul ul li a {
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     font-size: 11px;
     line-height: 27px;
     display: block;
     padding: 0 15px;
     /*transition for smooth hover animation*/
     transition: all 0.15s;
      }
     /*hover effect on links*/
     #accordian ul ul li a:hover {
     background: #003545;
     border-left: 5px solid lightgreen;
     }
    /*Lets hide the non active LIs by default*/
     #accordian ul ul {
     display: none;
     }
     #accordian li.active ul {
      display: block;
     }
     </style>
```

Can someone help me on how can I add a third level in this menu

Comment: You should be using a hierarchical view model so that you can ad as many levels as you want, and then you can use a recursive function to generate the html. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146524/how-to-render-singly-linked-list-in-mvc-view-page/27147744#27147744) for an example using a `HtmlHelper` extension method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a similar scenario, I used the Composite pattern to create the menu. In this way you can have submenus upto any level. So I have a Item, that can be either a unit menu or a menu containing submenus.

**The view model like:**

```
public class UserMenuOptions
{
    public bool IsSubMenu{get;set;}
    public string Text{get;set;}
    public string URL{get;set;}
    public string Page{get;set;}
    public List<UserMenuOptions> SubMenuList{get;set;}
    public UserMenuOptions(MenuItem item)
        {
            Text = item.MenuText;
            URL = item.Controller;
            Page = item.Action;
            IsSubMenu = false;
        }

        public UserMenuOptions(string text)
        {
            SubMenuList = new List<UserMenuOptions>();
            MenuText = text;
            IsSubMenu = true;
        }

        public void AddSubMenuItem(UserMenuOptions u)
        {
            this.SubMenuList.Add(u);
        }
    }
```

Sorry for the stupid naming.

And the `MenuItem` meaning the basic properties of a menu, that can be generated through business logic:

```
public sealed class MenuItem
    {
        public String MenuText { get; set; }        

        public String Controller { get; set; }

        public String Action { get; set; }
    }
```

**And then we have a partial view added to pages where we want the menu:**

```
@model List<UserMenuOptions>

<ul class="dropdown-menu">
        @foreach (UserMenuOptions mo in Model)
        {
            if(!mo.IsSubMenu){
                <li class="dropdown">@Html.ActionLink(mo.Text,mo.Page,mo.URL)</li>
            }
            else
            {
            <li class="dropdown-submenu" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <a href="#">@mo.Text</a>
                @{Html.RenderPartial("thisSamePartialView", mo.SubMenuList);}
            </li>
            }
        }
</ul>
```

OK, so we have the names of the links and the URLs of the links from some business logic.

Now we can construct a `List` (lets name it mainM)of `UserMenuOptions` which will be the top level of the menu structure. Now we have the main list on the menu, each item either can be a direct link or it has a submenu.

For instantiating a UserMenuOptions as a unit menu, we can use the first constructor, so that it has a URL. And in case the item is having submenus, we use the second constructor and AddSubMenuItem Methods to add nodes that will appear as the submenus.

We can repeat the last step for each item in each submenu to add next level submenus.

[image: PicToExplain]

And some styling would do the trick. Initially we need to pass the list of main headings to this partial.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply. I don't understand where to put your code and where the data are. Could you be more specific?

Comment: please mark the answer if it helped - so it helps future visitors as well ;). thx