# Formatting a Dropbox/ List not Working

Tags: html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

Currently I have a some hyperlinks that I am trying to put into a list that will make up the navigation. Before applying the dropdown menu the fix that I put in place to stop one label from re-occurring has stopped working. The  reason is this should have a main label and then have 3 sub-labels.

The labels should look like:
`Digital Format, Audio Visual, Selection Support, Bibliographic Data, E-Commerce`

Under Selection Support it should be:
`Web Site, Standing Orders, Water Stones, Out of Print`

Currently it does:
`Digital Format, Audio Visual, Selection Support, Selection Support, Selection Support, Selection Support, Bibliographic Data, E-Commerce`

Under each of the Selection Support then has one of each of the labels.

**The View I have for this is:**

```
<div style="font-family:Arial">
@{
    int stored = 0;
    int isInnerButton = 0;

    foreach (sidenav sidenav in @Model)
    {
        if (isInnerButton == 1)
        {
            isInnerButton = 0;      
        }
        if (sidenav.HasChild == 0)
        {
             <button class="btn btn-default" type="button">
                <a style="color:red" href='@Url.Action("content", new { id = sidenav.ContentID })' class="ajax3">@sidenav.DisplayLabel</a>
             </button>
        }
        else
        {
            if (sidenav.SideNavID != stored)
            {
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                @sidenav.DisplayLabel
                <span class="caret"></span>
                </button>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu"> 
                }
        <a style="color:blue" href='@Url.Action("content", new { id = sidenav.Level2ContentID })' class="ajax3">@sidenav.Level2DisplayLabel</a>
        stored = sidenav.SideNavID;
        isInnerButton = 1; 
        }
        }
        if (isInnerButton == 1){
         </ul>
                isInnerButton = 0;
        }
            }                                                                                  
         }
    }
</div>
```

**The Model I have for this is:**

```
[Table("AW_Wesbite")]
    public class sidenav
    {
        [Key]
        [column(order =1)]
        public int SideNavID {get; set;}
        [Key]
        [column(order =2)]
        public int MNavID {get; set;}
        [Key]
        [column(order =3)]
        public int MNavSubID {get; set;}
        [Key]
        [column(order =4)]
        public string DisplayLabel {get; set;}
        [Key]
        [column(order =5)]
        public int HasChild { get; set;}
        [Key]
        [column(order =6)]
        public int Priority {get; set;}
        [Key]
        [column(order =7)]
        public int? ContentID {get; set;}
        [Key]
        [column(order =8)]
     public int? SideNavSubID {get; set;}
        [Key]
        [column(order =9)]
        public string Level2DisplayLabel {get; set;}
        [Key]
        [column(order =10)]
        public int Level2Priority {get; set;}
        [Key]
        [column(order =11)]
        public int Level2ContentID {get; set;}
    }
```

Can anyone see where I have made the mistake to fix this code?

Comment: This must be the strangest code I have seen to create a hierarchical menu. Use a view model which contains a collection property for its sub-menus so you can use nested `foreach` loops (assuming its a maximum of 2 levels deep) or a recursive helper method to generate the html

Comment: The output that is generated is from view using two tables in SQL which is coded in the model.

Comment: Not sure what that has to do with it. You should have a model (say) `MenuVM` with properties `int ID`, `string Name` and `List<MenuVM> SubMenus` and you return `IEnumerable<MenuVM>` to the view and use a `foreach(var menu in Model) { // render link // if (menu.SubMenus.Any() { foreach(var submenu in menu.SubMenus) { ...`

Comment: And if you want it to be flexible and have unlimited sub levels, then [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146524/how-to-render-singly-linked-list-in-mvc-view-page/27147744#27147744) might help

Comment: My model looks like: `[Key] [Column(Order = 1)] public int SideNavID { get; set; }[Key][Column(Order = 2)]public int MNavID { get; set; } [Key][Column(Order = 3)] public int MNavSubID { get; set; } [Key] [Column(Order = 4)]public string DisplayLabel { get; set; }` The reason for doing it this was was due to the sub-navigation. If could post answer with the code I would be happy to see if this way would work?

Comment: You would need to edit the question with the model. But that does not seem to relate to your view which is referencing properties `ContentID`, `Level2ContentID` and `Level2DisplayLabel` which do not exist in that model?

Comment: I have missed those out of the model as there wasn't enough characters left to use to do this with. There are about 12 items within my view in SQL that is done by combining two tables together to create the model / view SideNav.

Comment: You need to edit you question to include the model and the query that you use to build that model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110721/discussion-between-terrortot38-and-stephen-muecke).

Comment: as requested I have now added the model into my question!!!