# How to traverse from model with dynamic child? Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How to traverse from model with dynamic child? I have this code but it will only work with only 3 step in the heirachy. How can I make it to traverse to all the children. Like if my 3rd child have another child and so on.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        @Model.Name
        @if (Model.ChildCategory.Count > 0)
        {
            <ul>
                @foreach (var child in Model.ChildCategory)
                {
                    <li>
                        <div>@child.Name</div>
                        @if (child.ChildCategory.Count > 0)
                        {
                            <ul>
                                @foreach (var secondChild in child.ChildCategory)
                                {
                                    <li><div>@secondChild.Name</div></li>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        }
                    </li>
                }
            </ul>
        }
    </li>
</ul>
```

and from my model this will output:

[image]

Comment: You need a hierarchical model and a recursive method. Refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146524/how-to-render-singly-linked-list-in-mvc-view-page/27147744#27147744) for an example using a `HtmlHelper` extension method

Comment: @StephenMuecke hi, your answers on the other question works great. thanks alot. if you post your answer i will mark it as accepted answers. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create your own Html Helper extension & with recursion you should be fine to traverse all child