# infinite menu recursive function C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html

I would like to know how I can create a recursive interface, I have a set of menus, these menus are parents having children and so on, since there are not a maximum number of children would like to find a solution to this problem, I left what I have done in **ASP.NET MVC** code and **C #**

```html
@foreach (var opcaoPai in opcoesPai)
            {

                var filhos = opcaoPai.OpcaoMenuFilhosSet.OrderBy(o => o.OrdemMenu);

            <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-info"  data-parent="#@opcaoPai.IdOpcao">
                <span>
                    @if (filhos.Any())
                    {
                        <a href="#@opcaoPai.IdOpcao" data-toggle="collapse">
                            <i style="float:left;margin-right:3px;" class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => opcaoPai.Titulo)
                        </a>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => opcaoPai.Titulo)
                    }
                </span>
                <!--<td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => opcaoPai.OrdemMenu)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (opcaoPai.IdAccao != null)
                    {
                        @(opcaoPai.AccaoSet.ControladorSet.PluginSet.Designacao + " - " + opcaoPai.AccaoSet.ControladorSet.Designacao + " - " + opcaoPai.AccaoSet.Designacao)
                    }
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => opcaoPai.OpcaoMenuPaiSet.Titulo)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => opcaoPai.ConteudoSet.Titulo)
                </td>-->
                <a href="@Url.Action("Apagar" ,new {id=opcaoPai.IdOpcao})" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;" id="menusgestao" type="btn" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btnmenus">
                    <i id="iconsmenugestao" class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>Eliminar
                </a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Detalhes", new {id=opcaoPai.IdOpcao})" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;" id="menusgestao" type="btn" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btnmenus">
                    <i id="iconsmenugestao" class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Detalhes
                </a>
                <a href="@Url.Action("Editar", new {id=opcaoPai.IdOpcao})" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;" id="menusgestao" type="btn" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btnmenus">
                    <i id="iconsmenugestao" class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>Editar
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="@opcaoPai.IdOpcao" class="collapse list-group-submenu">
                @foreach (var filho in filhos)
                {
                    <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#@opcaoPai.IdOpcao-@filho.IdOpcao">
                        <span>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => filho.Titulo)
                        </span>
                        <!--<td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => filho.OrdemMenu)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @if (filho.IdAccao != null)
                            {
                                @(filho.AccaoSet.ControladorSet.PluginSet.Designacao + " - " + filho.AccaoSet.ControladorSet.Designacao + " - " + filho.AccaoSet.Designacao)
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => filho.OpcaoMenuPaiSet.Titulo)
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => filho.ConteudoSet.Titulo)
                        </td>-->
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Apagar" ,new {id=filho.IdOpcao})" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;" id="menusgestao" type="btn" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btnmenus">
                            <i id="iconsmenugestao" class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i>Eliminar
                        </a>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Detalhes", new {id=filho.IdOpcao})" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;" id="menusgestao" type="btn" class="btn btn-info btn-xs btnmenus">
                            <i id="iconsmenugestao" class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>Detalhes
                        </a>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("Editar", new {id=filho.IdOpcao})" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;" id="menusgestao" type="btn" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs btnmenus">
                            <i id="iconsmenugestao" class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>Editar
                        </a>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        }
```

Comment: Refer  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27146524/how-to-render-singly-linked-list-in-mvc-view-page/27147744#27147744) for an example using a `HtmlHelper` extension method.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this structure:

```
public class Node {
  List<Node> Filhos {get;set;}
}
```

To render recursively, you just need to create an html render helper that receives a Node as parameter:

```
@helper RenderSomething(Node node) {
   // html to display node information
   foreach(Node filho in node.Filhos) {
     RenderSomething(filho);
   }
}
```

Comment: it receives the data from database so i need to make it work and i don't know and don't understand how because i need it to be infinite

Comment: The solution with the 'RenderSomething' is recursive and inifinte. Do you receive the data as a simple table, or through a list of childs, like with EF Lazy Loading?

Comment: I will be honest, that's my Intership and i don't know at 100% how it works but i receive it from a query from database not as a simple table i think

Comment: So you have this:`var filhos = opcaoPai.OpcaoMenuFilhosSet.OrderBy(o => o.OrdemMenu);` and then `foreach(var filho in filhos)`. Can I have a list  of filhos from the filho object? like `var filhos_filhos = filho.OpcaoMenuFilhosSet.OrderBy(o => o.OrdemMenu);`? If that's possible, then the helper is easy to implement. If not, then it depends on the structure of opcaoPai and filhos. Can you update your question with a detailed description of the opcaoPai and filhos?